# What are differences between "damage" and "injury"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-meaning

> He claimed serious injury to his reputation.

Can I use *damage*?

> The closure of the factory will cause severe damage to the local economy.

> The ship sustained only minor damage.

Can I use *injury*, instead of *damage*? Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tell someone about *serious injury*, the first thing comes is the physical harm to someone.

OALD defines this word and it is mostly used for physical harm

> [injury](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/injury) - harm done to a person's or an animal's body, for example in an accident

However, **injury** can happen to someone's *feeling* (on the same page).

> injury - Damages may be awarded for emotional injury.

In usage note *injury* OALD defines *being injured* where instances are of physically being hurt.

Being a medical professional, I'd like to mention that *damage* can also happen to human organs (especially internal) but then it could be the *result of an injury* or harm by bad microorganisms

> In that road accident, he got several injuries. In fact, his *liver* is damaged and needs to be repaired. OR 
>  I have never seen such worse septicemia. Her internal organs are damaged and will stop working soon.

But again, if you are talking about someone's reputation or *injury* in the context of *non-living* thing, use **[damage](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/damage_1)** to keep ambiguity at bay.

Don't get confuse that *damage* can be used for physical harm. ['Physical'](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/PHYSICAL) can be used for non living things like computers and books etc. :)

So, a *ship* is a non-living thing so it might sustain *damage* and let the closer cause *damage* to the economy, not *injury*. :)

Comment: You omitted one important note about the context of *injury* being used for "damage to a person's feelings". Your dictionary says "(law)".

Comment: It isn't related to the OP Question, but "such worse" does not sound like natural English.

Comment: @TecBrat not sure what do you mean by *natural* English!  *"...have been terrifically disturbed **due to such worse** weather condition.* - from the US Trade Media

Answer (score 3):

> **Injury**: a wound or damage to part of your body caused by an accident or attack.

For example: "She was taken to hospital with serious head injuries."
So because the word *injury* is used for animate person, we cannot use *damage* instead of it.

> **Damage**: physical harm that is done to something or to a part of someone's body, so that it is broken or injured.

For example: "These chemicals have been found to cause  serious environmental damage."
So we cannot use *injury* instead of *damage* in that sentence.

Comment: Do you notice that each definition includes the other word?

Answer (score -1):

In the case of *He claims serious injury to his **reputation***;

Here, the reputation of a certain person is *personified*.(why?)

Lets get thorough with the definitions first:

*An injury affects a living organism, the likes of you and me*

*Damage affects a non-living object, like a car*

So they can **not** be used interchangeably.

Lets get back to your word usage:

> He claimed serious *damage* to his reputation

Is absolutely correct.

> The closure of the factory will cause severe *injury* to the economy.

Is incorrect and should be replaced with *damage*.

> The ship sustained only minor *damage* is correct. *Injury* here is incorrect.

Comment: _In general_, **injury** would be damage to a living thing, while **damage** would be injury to a non-living thing. :) There _are_ special cases, such as the legal term _injury to your reputation_. However, you can seldom go wrong restricting _injury_ to living things (including plants) and _damage_ to anything else, both tangible and intangible objects.